# Mysql - find missing months in specific dated records

Tags: mysql

I have a table with salary records of employees

```
employee_table (employee_idn, pay_date, pay_amount)
employee_idn pay_date pay_amount
1, 2017-04-17,  100  
1, 2017-05-17,  100    
1, 2017-08-17,  100  
2, 2017-04-17,  200  
2, 2017-09-17,  200    
3, 2017-08-17,  500
```

If I pass in a date range `"2017-04-01" to "2018-03-31"`, I would like to know by employee which months the user has not been paid (missing months) until the end date. So for result set, by employee, for example, employee_idn (1), i would like to get back

```
1, 2017-06-30,  0  
1, 2017-07-31,  0    
1, 2017-09-30,  0 
1, 2017-10-31,  0 
1, 2017-11-30,  0 
1, 2017-12-31,  0 
1, 2018-01-31,  0 
1, 2018-02-28,  0  
1, 2018-03-31,  0
```

and the same for other employees (2,3).

My mysql version is 5.1.30-community-log

I have tried multiple ways but with no luck. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a calender/dates table?

Comment: I am creating a calendar table which has all dates for over 100 years.

Comment: Create running MYSQL fiddle with schema and seed data. I will try

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/54b811/1

Comment: Any help from the community will be appreciated. I am not able to figure out an answer.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do this via your script side, you cannot rely always on the database to do such thing, you code will be much faster if you do it since there is ready made functions that can deal with the date range.

Comment: I would still like to use database to do this as the number of records are a lot and mysql will process it much more faster & efficiently instead of looping through all the employees and finding missing dates.